# Как еще может быть ограничен доступ к сайту?

Tags: .htaccess

Сайт закрыт авторизацией с помощью .htaccess (как я думаю). Но в файле .htaccess нет ни одной строчки Auth*. Чем он может быть закрыт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скриптом можно так же оградить.

```
if ( $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] != "admin" || $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] != "123456" ) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Мой сайт"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        die('<h1>Не лезть!.</h1>');

}
```

Это на php.